# Populate dropdown box from SQL Server using a function

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am trying to follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkiYuPBwnkQ) that is written in C# and convert it to vb (to Populate a dropdown box from SQL Server using a function)
here is the working C# code:

```
private list<product> getallprodcuts()
{
    Try
    {
          using(PropSolWebDBEntities db= new PropSolWebDBEntities())
          list<product> products = (from x in db.product select x).tolist;
    }
    catch(exception)
    {
           Return Null;
    }
}
```

And the vb that I cant get to work:

```
Private Function getallproducts() As List( Of<product>)

        Try
            Dim db As New PropSolWebDBEntities
            Dim products As list <product> = (from x in db.product select x).tolist 

            Return products

        Catch ex As Exception
            Return vbNull
        End Try
    End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to document your question a little better.  Is it throwing an error? What happens when you step through the code?  Is there anything in the list?  Your c# example isn't returning the results, by the way.  Details matter.  For VB.Net, you probably should return Nothing instead of vbNull.

Comment: The code you're using is swallowing the exception (if any are thrown), which is a bad practice.

Comment: Sorry I will word it better next time. Thx for all your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List should be translated as List(of product).

return null should be translated as Return Nothing.

Use using instead of declaring the db variable.

I don't compile the code, but it's like this:

```
Private Function getallproducts() As List(Of product)

Try
    Using db As New PropSolWebDBEntities
        Dim products As list(Of product) = (From x In db.product Select x).ToList()
        Return products
    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    Return Nothing
End Try
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `LINQ` part since you are not filtering/grouping/ordering by. The `Using` block takes care of your context disposal for you. You just missed some syntax difference.

```
Private Function getallproducts() As List(Of product)
  Dim results As List(Of product) = Nothing
  Using db As New PropSolWebDBEntities
     results = db.product.ToList 
  End Using
  Return results
End Function
```